# Why is necessary the concat()/ slice(0)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is a question from CodeWars that is named "Find the middle element". I try to solve it by below code:

```
var gimme = function (a) {
    return a.indexOf(a.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b })[1]);
};
```

but it can't work, it need add concat() or slice(0). the correct answer is:

```
return a.indexOf(a.concat().sort(function(a, b) { return a - b })[1]);
```

But I don't know why? Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what the original question was, not just that it's "on codewars"? Without knowing how the function is called, with what arguments, this can't be answered.

Comment: `sort` modifies the original array. `concat` and `slice` make a copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely because they wanted you to do it in a clean way that doesn't modify the parameters (which is generally a no-no that should be avoided).

By using `concat()` and/or `slice(0)`, you create a new instance of the array, so you aren't modifying the original entered array.

```js
const a = [3,1,2];
const b = [3,1,2];

const dangerous = (arr) => arr.sort();
const safe = (arr) => arr.slice(0).sort();

const d = dangerous(a);
const s = safe(b);

console.log(a, d, a === d);
console.log(b, s, b === s);
```

Notice how the `dangerous()` function actually changed our `a`, which could have unintended and difficult to find consequences. `b` doesn't get changes with `safe()` and a new array is created instead.